# navigation transition hangs during Future

Tags: flutter

i have the below code , that when the button is pressed on Page1() , the future is executed when Page2() loads, but the CircularProgressIndicator() "freezes", until the future completes.  I have tried this with BottomNavigationBar as well, and the "slide-in" freezes half way there as well.

is there a more idiomatic way to do this so that Page2() renders fully while the future is running ?

```
//-----------------------
    //main.dart
    //-----------------------

    void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/' : (BuildContext context) => Page1(),
        '/page2' : (BuildContext context) => Page2()
      }
    );
  }
}

//-----------------------
//page1.dart
//-----------------------

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Page 1')),
         body: Container(
           child: Column(children: <Widget>[
             Text('Page 1 header'),
             RaisedButton(
               child: Text('Click me'),
               onPressed: ()  {
                 Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/page2');
                 })
           ],),)
         );
    }
}

//-----------------------
//page2.dart
//-----------------------

class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _Page2State();
  }
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {
  MainModel model = MainModel();

  void initState() {
    model.fetchData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Page 2')),
        body: ScopedModel<MainModel>(
            model: model,
            child: ScopedModelDescendant(
                builder: (context, child, MainModel model) {
              if (model.isLoading) {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else {
                return Container(
                    child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Page 2 body'),
                  ],
                ));
              }
            })));
  }
}


//-----------------------
//main_model.dart
//-----------------------
class MainModel extends Model {

    bool _isLoading = false;
    bool get isLoading => _isLoading;

  void fetchData() async {

      _isLoading = true;
      notifyListeners();

      final String url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';

      await http.get(url)
          .then<Null>((http.Response response) {
            print('${DateTime.now()} In http response and about to sleep');
            sleep(const Duration(seconds:5));
            print('${DateTime.now()} done sleeping');

            _isLoading = false;
            notifyListeners();
            return;
          }
      ).catchError((error) {
        print('Error: $error');
        _isLoading = false;
        notifyListeners();
        return;
      });

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `sleep()` method freezes the ui.

You could try a `Future.delayed()` in the following way:

```
class MainModel extends Model {
  bool _isLoading = false;

  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;

  void fetchData() {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    final String url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';

    http.get(url).then<Null>((http.Response response) {
      print('${DateTime.now()} In http response and about to sleep');
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
        _isLoading = false;
        notifyListeners();
        print('${DateTime.now()} done sleeping');
      });
    }).catchError((error) {
      print('Error: $error');
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      return;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.  I figured since sleep was running in the future with http, it shouldn't block the UI.  Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 0):

[Flutter recommends using the `FutureBuilder` widget when working with async data sources](https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/fetch-data/). For example:

```
FutureBuilder<Post>(
  future: fetchPost(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text(snapshot.data.title);
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
    }

    // By default, show a loading spinner
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
);
```

This way the `CircularProgressIndicator` will keep running whilst your Page2 loads the API data.

Comment: My understanding is with scoped_model, FutureBuilder should not be necessary, no?  Can you show an example with scoped_model?